# WCF configuration not honored

Tags: wcf, configuration

We have some weird behavior with WCF bindings configured in configuration files.
We do service calls that may be long-running so we need a send-/operation-timeout longer than the default 1 minute.
Our WCF configuration reflects that, setting sendTimeout to 10 minutes.

But if the service call exceeds 1 minute there is an error message saying the operation timed out after 1 minute at the one-minute mark.
Debugging this we check whether the configuration is correct, like this (here the service call made is shorter than 1 minute for the purpose of debugging):

```
public class MyWcfClient : ClientBase<IMyWcf>, IMyWcf 
{
    public ResultType MyMethod()
    {
        var originalBinding = base.Endpoint.Binding;

        var result = this.Channel.MyMethod();

        var changedBinding = base.Endpoint.Binding;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Here originalBinding will contain the configured settings (sendTimeout = 10 minutes, etc.). But after the call, checking the changedBinding variable, there are other values in the binding, among others the sendTimeout is 1 minute 
and it seems the latter one is the one used by the service-call considering the timeout response when making a long-running call. The type of the binding has changed as well from NetTcpBinding to CustomBinding.

Now changing the code slightly, to:

```
public class MyWcfClient : ClientBase<IMyWcf>, IMyWcf 
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var originalBinding = base.Endpoint.Binding;

        var sendTimeout = ((IContextChannel)base.Channel).OperationTimeout;

        var changedBinding = base.Endpoint.Binding;     
    }
}
```

Here we get the same behavior when it comes to the binding values as before. The variable sendTimeout gets value 1 minute, so again it seems the changed binding value is the one honored.

A third example, setting OperationTimeout explicitly before making the service call the set value is honored.

```
public class MyWcfClient : ClientBase<IMyWcf>, IMyWcf 
{
    public ResultType MyMethod()
    {
        ((IContextChannel)base.Channel).OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        var result = this.Channel.MyMethod();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here when making a long-running service-call (though less than 10 minutes) there is no timeout.

So it works setting timeout explicitly in code but we would like to do it all in configuration files.

The binding looks similar to this (same on server and client side):

```
<binding name="NetTcpBinding" 
    sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
    openTimeout="00:10:00" 
    closeTimeout="00:10:00"
    transactionFlow="false" 
    portSharingEnabled="true" 
    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
    maxBufferSize="2147483647" >
    ... 
</binding>
```

Any ideas on the explanation for this? What can we do for the configuration to be honored?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a bug in the telemetryClient Wcf-extension. Without it the binding is kept and the timeout works.

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-SDK-Labs/issues/124